# Change mouse cursor while hover over specific canvas paths with Paper.js

Tags: html5-canvas, paperjs

Actually (using w3.org doc's example http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/2dcontext/html5_canvas/#dom-context-2d-ispointinpath) I did figured out how it could be done in raw HTML5Canvas/JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/QTu9E/4/

Above I used `isPointInPath(x, y)` syntax, but according to mentioned docs there is also `isPointInPath(path, x, y[, w ])` in which certain path can be given to check.

This one could be problem solver, but I can't get it work just passing paperjs's `Path` object into it!

I'll continue searching for solution, because as anyone else I have my deadlines, but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying that is not working? Code would be helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here is the answer!

http://jsfiddle.net/fqaJM/

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="256" height="128"></canvas>
<div id="xycoordinates"></div>
```

```
#myCanvas {
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
}
#xycoordinates {
    font: 9pt sans-serif;
}
```

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); // Get canvas

// Some initialisation stuff to make things work out of PaperScript context
// Have to have things to be done this way because jsfiddle don't allow to save source with script type="text/paperscript"
paper.install(window); 
paper.setup(canvas);   

var myPath = new paper.Path.Circle([64, 64], 32); // Red one, with 'pointer' cursor on it
myPath.style = {
    fillColor: '#FF0000'
};
var scndPath = new paper.Path.Circle([192, 64], 32); // Green one, without cursor accent
scndPath.style = {
    fillColor: '#00FF00'
};
paper.view.draw(); // Have to call manually when working from JavaScript directly

var hitOptions = { // Trigger hit only on 'fill' part of the path with 0 tolerance
    segments: false,
    stroke: false,
    fill: true,
    tolerance: 0
};

var tool = new paper.Tool(); // Again manually. Life is much easier with script type="text/paperscript"
tool.onMouseMove = function (event) { // Installig paperjs event 
    var x = event.point.x;
    var y = event.point.y;

    document.getElementById("xycoordinates").innerHTML = "Coordinates: (" + x + "," + y + ")";

    var hitResult = myPath.hitTest(event.point, hitOptions); // isPointInPath

    if (hitResult) {
        document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
    } else {
        document.body.style.cursor = "default";
    }
};
```

The point is I missed paperjs has its own `onMouseMove` and `hitTest()`, which is `isPointInPath()` wrapper.

Don't know how did it happen, because I'm already using it in project! Perhabs need to have some rest %)

And any way, there are still some problems: it looks like `hitTest()` fires up some strange false positives, sontimes it doesn't trigger where it should. Check out point with (46,96) and (77,64) coordinates!

UPD: Just tested the same code in one HTML file localy to get same artifacts: http://pastebin.com/HiYgKnw0

Comment: Links are dead.

Answer (score 5):

Try the `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` events and change the css style of the paperjs containers html dom element.

http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#onmouseenter

```
yourPath.onMouseEnter = function (event) {
    paperCanvasContainerDiv.style.cursor = "pointer";
}
yourPath.onMouseLeave = function (event) {
    paperCanvasContainerDiv.style.cursor = "default";
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (for obvious reasons)!

Comment: With `view.element` you are also able to get a reference to the canvas.